# Web GUI frameworks for Phone development

Tags: user-interface, delphi, mobile

I looked already and couldn't find anything good.

So a question is, are there any good web frameworks that would allow to easily develop GUI for the majority of high end phones? By this I mean

1. It would have to work "the same" on majority of high end phones (forget the low cost ones)
2. It would have to simplify the development and hide the ugly details from developer
3. Clear design and good documentation. Also some stability on the market.
4. The focus is on good looking and easy to make GUI. Javascript is only a plus.

So basically I am looking for something like jQuery or maybe ExtJS for phone development.

EDIT:

It would be a big plus if it could be consumed in Delphi

EDIT 2:

If it was not clear, I am looking for a web base solution that would run in a browser. So the target is HTML output and not native code.

Comment: If you're looking for "something like jQuery" that can "run in a browser," then you're looking for jQuery.

Comment: No, If you look at how pages look on mobile devices you will know what I mean. The browser support is completely different. Take a look at Blackberry Web manual. Certain devices support only subset of HTML and CSS. They are terrible with table type display. And javascirpt is very poory supported on some. What I need is a framework tha would help me construct a GUI and not worry about HTML, CSS and javascript level of support on various high end devices.

Comment: As no truly good answers came and mine at least covers a wide variety of choices, I am forced to accept my own answer as much as I hate doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To contribute to the subject. I found a question that has answers to such topic:

[iWebkit vs. JQTouch vs. iUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980573/iwebkit-vs-jqtouch-vs-iui)

So there seem to be the following frameworks:

1. iUI
2. jQTouch
3. WebApp.net
4. iWebKit
5. Yahoo! Blueprint
6. JQTouch
7. PhoneGap
8. Sencha Touch
9. jQueryMobile

PhoneGap supports a wide variety of phones but it does so by making native (or interpreted I don't know) code to run on them, so it is a no go for me.

Yahoo! Blueprint supports a lot of phones also, but seems to need a special framework to run on. So also a no go.

jQTouch and WebApp.net look promissing, but they only support webkit based browsers. Yes these are in majority these days probably, but Blackberry for one has non webkit based browser and Blackberry is very important to me.

I will keep looking, in the meantime, don't be shy to contribute ;)

**EDIT**

Found this wiki about some frameworks. Most are embedded.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_phone_web_based_application_framework

**EDIT2**

I added Sencha Touch (www.sencha.com/products/touch) to the list as it was added after this post was created. They are the former ExtJS and now have the WebKit based mobile solution.

**EDIT3**

I added jQuery Mobile (http://jquerymobile.com/) to the list as it was added after this post was created.

Answer (score 2):

[Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch) seams to be the solution. Since [UniGui](http://www.unigui.com) for Delphi/Lazarus already supports eye catching ExtJS it would be ideal if it extends to Sencha Touch. We will see.

Comment: True, for now it is the most complete solution for WebKit based browsers. There just ins't enything better a the moment. And for the update, I went with Sencha Touch for my solution that spawned this question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused, do you want a web framework that runs on the web for phones (like [jqTouch](http://www.jqtouch.com/)), or are you looking for something that will create native apps provides some amount of portability (like [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/)/C#)?

Comment: I updated the question. I am looking for a web based solution to be viewed in a browser. I will look at jqTouch.

Comment: Now I remember I already came upon jqTouch, but it is not what I want as it only supports iPhone and related devices.

Answer (score 1):

lightweight jquery-like alternative that works on android & iphone (& possibly blackberry & winmo) is xui, cfr. http://xuijs.com/documentation and http://github.com/brianleroux/xui.

edit: xui is more about javascript and less about a good looking GUI, so this might not be what you're looking for after all.

Comment: Yes, these are javascript micro-frameworks. I am looking more into GUI possibilies. Javascript is only a plus here.

Answer (score 1):

http://jquerymobile.com/

... when its released in "Late 2010".