# iWebkit Vs JqueryMobile Vs JQtouch?

Tags: jquery, iphone

Hii Friends,

```
i m newbie to iphone development , i have to design a iphone webapp,have found these three have the best features,
```

Plz point out these pros and cons of these mobile frameworks?

Does php is needed for form processing or we can use xml,feeds etc?

Comment: please post some info about your app scenario. It's hard to give you some peace of advice without some details.

Comment: yes sure & thanks, My app is to create a college alumini site where users can access feeds, articles etc. does php is needed or i can use client side storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a little survey [here](http://iphoneized.com/2009/11/18-mobile-frameworks-development-tools-creating-iphone-apps/).
Also, I suggest you to look at this answer from the user Adrian Kosmaczewski [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980573/iwebkit-vs-jqtouch-vs-iui), and at his slides (see the link inside the his answer).

Then...

**If you *don't want* to code it yourself:**
A good solution would be to use [Wordpress](http://wordpress.com) with [this](http://iwphone.contentrobot.com/2007/07/04/iwphone-wordpress-plugin-and-theme/) or some other mobile plugin. You will easily get a robust blog/cms(sort of), feeds and a lot more.

**If you *want* to code It yourself**:
Any server side technology could be good but I'm a strong fan of ruby and rails. I will add to It [jquerymobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) because it have John Resig (jquery creator and lead developer) behind :) and because supports a lot of mobile platforms.