# How to create a mobile interface for Grails apps?

Tags: iphone, grails, user-interface, mobile, grails-plugin

I'd like to have a mobile interface for my Grails app, and am wondering how to go about it, namely how to create the UI.
Google search quickly revealed [iUI](http://code.google.com/p/iui/) and the [iUI Grails plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/iui). Both don't seem to be maintained any longer, last releases being in 2009. Despite their version numbers, are they in a usable state?
Are there any alternatives? I remember seeing another plugin for this, but now I cannot find it.

Right now, all we have are iphone clients. In the long run, does a web-app benefit from a vendor-neutral interface, or is it more prudent to create an interface per platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest that you look at [Mobl-lang](http://www.mobl-lang.org/), [JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) or [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) as your frontend and let your Grails app deliver data to the frontend as JSON

Comment: Thank you, those look promising. Are they available free to open-source developers?

Comment: Mobl and JQuery is free, I don't know about PhoneGap

Comment: According to http://www.phonegap.com/about/license, PhoneGap is free under either the BSD or the MIT license.

Answer (score 1):

There is grails plugin for iphone like layout http://www.grails.org/plugin/iwebkit.

Here is the reference to stack-overflow ticket which discusses the same issue.

[iWebkit vs. JQTouch vs. iUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980573/iwebkit-vs-jqtouch-vs-iui)

Comment: That's the other one I remembered. Thank you. Can you compare iUI and iWebkit?